# Give bit_length find all possible integer in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
input bit_lenght = 3                            input bit_length = 2
output [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]                        output [0,1,2,3]
```

Any build-in function can help to achieve this result easily?

Comment: How about `list(range(2**bit_length))`?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Should have think about that.